# Problema ao criar cliente customer

Tags: node.js

Não estou a conseguir criar um cliente no jasmin.
Consigo criar uma factura, e aceder aos dados, mas criar um cliente não estou a conseguir.

Este é o pedido que estou a fazer em js:

```js
function createClient(token) {
  var firstPartyClient = {
    "customerGroup": "01",
    "paymentMethod": "CC_DINHEIRO",
    "paymentTerm": "00",
    "partyTaxSchema": "IVA-RN-MN",
    "locked": false,
    "accountingSchema": 1,
    "oneTimeCustomer": false,
    "endCustomer": true,
    "partyKey": "NewCustomer",
    "searchTerm": "NewCustomer",
    "name": "NewCustomer",
    "isExternallyManaged": false,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "country": "PT",
    "isPerson": true
  };

  request({
      uri: customerParties,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      data: firstPartyClient,
      method: 'POST'
    }, function (err, res, body) {
      console.log(res);

      console.log("status: "+res.statusCode);
      console.log("status: "+err);
    });
}
```

O erro que obtenho é:

```js
"{
  "validations": [
    {
      "propertyName": "customerPartyResource",
      "errorMessage": "Ambiguous match found."
    }
  ]
}"
```

Não sei se é o pedido que está mal.

Comment: Podes colocar aqui a uri que estás a usar?

Comment: Sim,
`uri:'https://my.jasminsoftware.com/api/<tenant>/<organization>/salescore/customerParties'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver.
Alterei para a forma como fazia o pedido:

```js
request.post({
      url: customerParties,
      headers: header,
      body: partyClient,
      json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body)
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body)
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
  });
```

Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Efetuei exatamente esta chamada pelo POSTMAN e ocorreu sem problemas, quer criando a Party, quer criando uma customerParty.
Valide se está a fazer a chamada para o endpoint correto e se funciona usando o postman.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não tinha testado, mas sim deu.
Mudei a forma como estava a fazer o pedido para:
´request.post({`e ja deu!
Obrigado.
O partyKey tem que ser sempre gerado por mim? Não tem forma de vir do sistema o próximo partyKey?

Comment: Sugiro que coloque esta pergunta como respondida e coloque uma nova para que mais utilizadores a possam ver e ajudar.